# Inserting query in Database through Selenium Webdriver Error appears: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

If I am inserting only text and number then it will accept this but if I am Using **'** Single inverted commas then error through.
Here is the code

```
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Registration;
  String preValue = "SELECT * FROM 'users' where email='Email@Email.com'";
  js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[1].innerText='" + preValue + "';");


org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

System info: host: 'AZAD-PC', ip: '192.168.1.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
```

Comment: Can you please add the complete error stack trace. I think you need to add wild cards inside the string that you've entered.

Comment: If you manually insert the `preValue` string into the JS command, you will end up with `'` inside of `'` quoted string which is the problem. You are closing your string prematurely. Is there some reason you are inserting this all using JS instead of just using Selenium to `.sendKeys()`?

Comment: Hi JeffC .sendKeys() is not working, Element is only locating through Javascript.

Comment: Hi @demouser123 sorry for the late reply..but how Can I add the wild cards inside the string...Can u please provide the code or some Hint.

Comment: HI I have edited the Question section with Error....Please check the error.

Comment: and **Thank you** both of u for Reply.